# Radio-button checked overriden by ngModel

Tags: angular, ionic3, radio-button, angular-ngmodel

When declaring a ngModel to a radio group it appears to override the default radio button selection assigned by [checked]="true"

```
     <!--Radio buttons for units-->
      <ion-list-header style="color: white">
        Units
      </ion-list-header>
   <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="units">
   
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Metric</ion-label>
      <ion-radio [checked]="true"  value= "metric"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Imperial</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="imperial"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Therefore there is no checked button by default when the button group is in view.

I have tried placing the ngModel within the radio button tag, the ion-item tag, both methods throw an exception:

> Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for
> form control with unspecified name attribute
> _throwError@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:27548:20

Any inout appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're binding the radio group to the `units` property, you don't need to use the `checked` attribute in your template.

In order to select one of the options by default, you just need to assign the value of that option to the `units` property:

```
private someFunction(): void {
  // ...
  this.units = 'metric'; 
}
```

```
<!--Radio buttons for units-->
<ion-list-header style="color: white">
  Units
</ion-list-header>
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="units">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Metric</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value= "metric"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Imperial</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="imperial"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```